# Have both redirects for HTTP to HTTPS and canonical/aliases working together

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, httpd

I'm having issues with having both rules work at the same time, my conf file follow

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mytest.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.mytest.domain.com mytest2.domain.com www.mytest2.domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^ https://mytest.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName redirects.for.mytest.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.mytest.domain.com mytest2.domain.com www.mytest2.domain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://mytest.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mytest.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mytest/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      my.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile my.chain
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   my.key
</VirtualHost>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Everything from HTTP is redirected to HTTPS
- All aliases and www domains must redirect to its 'principal' version

I can do one or the other, but mixing both creates an infinite redirect loop, whats the proper way?